# disable apache permanently and use only nginx

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, centos, node.js

I'm running nodejs on localhost and nginx to set up reverse proxy server on a VPS.
Using TMUX I'm starting both nginx and nodejs and detaching from the session. I have tried disabling apache alot times but still it keeps turning on and stops nginx. I have tried following commands.

```
     # chkconfig httpd off
     # /etc/init.d/httpd stop
     # chkconfig --list | grep httpd
     # httpd           0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
```

Even though everything is off it still keeps turning on. Guess there something else thats restarting apache.

Its my first time using Linux. I'm not able to keep my site up because of this. Any help would keep my site live.

Comment: Why don't you just remove the Apache package if you don't need it?

Comment: I thought it would have some dependencies and might affect other programs. If not I will do it immediately.

Comment: Check what `yum` reports if you try it. Normally, nginx should be a replacement.

Comment: Used the following command and removed it.  # yum erase httpd httpd-tools apr apr-util

Comment: Didn't work. # yum info httpd says no matching packages to list. But # httpd -v gives Apache installed on cpanel.

Comment: Disabled httpd on cpanel. Hope it works this time.

Answer (score 1):

centos7? systemd?

```
systemctl stop httpd
systemctl disable httpd
systemctl mask httpd
```

in case of centos6, you could just try to just chmod -x httpd or anything else used to start apache:

```
chmod -x /usr/sbin/httpd /usr/sbin/apachectl
```

Comment: Centos6. systemctl was not working